# I want to sum the GDP per capita for all the countries in Europe, for all the years from the following data set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

```
import pandas as pd

## the following is my dataset

gm = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gerberl/6G7V0026-2223/main/datasets/gapminder.tsv', sep='\t')

gm.iloc[8:15]
```

[image]

The data frame looks something like this.
So I am trying extract the gdp per capita of europe over the years. I am using the following syntax:

```
gm.groupby(['country','year'])["gdpPercap"].sum()
```

[image]

How can i only sum for countries in Europe?

Answer (score 0):

First select European countries, group by country and summarize:

```
gm.loc[gm['continent'] == 'Europe'].groupby(['country'])['gdpPercap'].sum()


country
Albania                    39064.399592
Austria                   244942.995352
Belgium                   238809.096860
Bosnia and Herzegovina     41817.348833
Bulgaria                   76608.662064
Croatia                   111980.548151
Czech Republic            167040.136548
Denmark                   260061.898655
Finland                   209684.672008
France                    226002.843925
Germany                   246680.213193
Greece                    167628.441995
Hungary                   130658.107844
Iceland                   246377.067270
Ireland                   189103.274853
Italy                     194942.508077
Montenegro                 86496.774717
Netherlands               260986.226498
Norway                    320967.678650
Poland                    100998.646947
Portugal                  136249.103129
Romania                    87602.039683
Serbia                    111660.593329
Slovak Republic           124986.368268
Slovenia                  168894.985312
Spain                     168357.917745
Sweden                    239317.513248
Switzerland               324892.012860
Turkey                     53633.440556
United Kingdom            232565.675827
Name: gdpPercap, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

First Filter then, Group

```
import pandas as pd

gm = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gerberl/6G7V0026-2223/main/datasets/gapminder.tsv', sep='\t')

df_Europe= gm[gm['continent'].str.contains("Europe")]   

df_Europe =df_Europe.groupby(['country','year'])["gdpPercap"].sum()

print(df_Europe)
```

#ouput

```
country         year
Albania         1952     1601.056136
                1957     1942.284244
                1962     2312.888958
                1967     2760.196931
                1972     3313.422188
                            ...     
United Kingdom  1987    21664.787670
                1992    22705.092540
                1997    26074.531360
                2002    29478.999190
                2007    33203.261280
```