# I can't groupby the data with pandas for world GDP data

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am kinda new to Python but not new to coding. I thought the following coding was going to be easy but I couldn't produce the result that I needed.

I have the data from [https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/gdp-per-capita-maddison?tab=chart&country=JPN~USA~GBR~DEU~FRA](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/gdp-per-capita-maddison?tab=chart&country=JPN%7EUSA%7EGBR%7EDEU%7EFRA)
It has ['Entity', 'Code', 'Year', 'GDP per capita', '417485-annotations']

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

WorldData = pd.read_csv('gdp-per-capita-maddison.csv')
#Stripping the white spaces
WorldData.columns = WorldData.columns.str.strip()
columns=WorldData.columns.tolist()

# Dropping Code of the countries and also Annotations column
WorldData=WorldData.drop([columns[1],columns[-1]], axis=1)

grouped=WorldData.groupby(['Entity'],dropna=True)

print(grouped)
print(grouped.head())
```

First I can't print grouped. And if I change to print(grouped.head()) I see the whole dataset which is not grouped (See figure 1)
[image]

I can create a pivot table in Google sheet with "Entity", therefore, I think there is nothing wrong with the data.

Edit: To clarify: My goal is to be able to create an interactive line plot that plots GDP over the years of 3 selected countries. Therefore, I need (I think I need) to create something like
[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74090700/i-want-to-sum-the-gdp-per-capita-for-all-the-countries-in-europe-for-all-the-ye]

Comment: Note - there are errors in the CSV file specifically some Years with  value 1. This will distort plots if you use all the data for countries with such errors. I suggest filtering data for Years greater than some value of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the output you showed, the `.groupby()` method returns an object of type [`DataFrameGroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html), which is not in itself a DataFrame. However, it will yield tuples of `(key, df)` when you [iterate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.__iter__.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.__iter__) over it, where `key` in your case will be the relevant "Entity" value, and `df` *will* be the grouped DataFrame of entries with that value, as you expect. So, the typical way to use `groupby()` here would be something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

WorldData = pd.read_csv('gdp-per-capita-maddison.csv')
# stripping the white spaces
WorldData.columns = WorldData.columns.str.strip()
columns = WorldData.columns.tolist()

# dropping country code and annotations columns
WorldData=WorldData.drop([columns[1], columns[-1]], axis=1)

grouped = WorldData.groupby(['Entity'], dropna=True)
for country, dataframe in grouped:
    print("Plotting data for country", country)
    plt.plot(dataframe["Year"], dataframe["GDP per capita"], label=country)
    # (or however you want to handle the plotting)
```

Alternatively, `DataFrameGroupBy` objects actually have a [`.plot()` method of their own](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot.html), so for this use case, you can omit the iteration and simply call

```py
grouped.plot(x="Year", y="GDP per capita", ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I actually when in a different direction with the inspiration from you.