# Legends of Interactive plot with jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, plot, jupyter-notebook, interactive

I am plotting GDP of countries using interactive plotting. I actually managed almost all I wanted. But I would like also to add legends however I am failing to do so. I got the data from https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/gdp-per-capita-maddison?tab=chart&country=JPN%7EUSA%7EGBR%7EDEU%7EFRA

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from ipywidgets import interact
import ipywidgets as widgets
WorldData = pd.read_csv('gdp-per-capita-maddison.csv')

# stripping the white spaces
#WorldData.columns = WorldData.columns.str.strip()
columns = WorldData.columns.tolist()

# dropping country code and annotations columns
WorldData=WorldData.drop([columns[1], columns[-1]], axis=1).reset_index()

# GETTING THE NAMES OF THE COUNTRIES
Countries=WorldData["Entity"].unique()

# GETTING COLOR AND MARKER OPTIONS FOR THE PLOT
colorss=["r","g","b","y","k","m","c","k"]
markers=['o','+','v','<','s','*',"d",'None']
liness=["dashed","-","-.","--",":","dashed",":",":"]

# HERE PLOTTING IS STARTING
@interact(col_names=widgets.SelectMultiple(options=Countries,value=. 
(Countries[0],),description='Countries'))
def plotting(col_names):

   ax=plt.figure(figsize=[12,8])
   ax=plt.gcf().suptitle("GDP of Countries by year")


   i=0
   while i<len(col_names):
      clm=random.randint(0, 7)    # RANDOMLY PICKING THE COLOR AND LINE ETC. 
      ax=plt.legend(col_names[i]) # NOT WORKING
      DfA=WorldData[WorldData["Entity"]==col_names[i]] # GETTING THE DATA FOR THE 
      #COUNTRY
      ax=plt.plot(DfA["Year"], DfA["GDP per capita"],color=colorss[clm], 
      linestyle=liness[clm], marker=markers[clm])
      i=i+1
#plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

# SOME IMPORTANT DATES 
plt.axvline(x = 1914, color = 'r', linestyle = '--') 
plt.axvline(x = 1918, color = 'r', linestyle = '--') 
plt.axvline(x = 1929, color = 'k', linestyle = '--') 
plt.axvline(x = 1939, color = 'k', linestyle = '--')
plt.axvline(x = 1939, color = 'b', linestyle = '--')
plt.axvline(x = 1945, color = 'b', linestyle = '--')
plt.axvline(x = 1989, color = 'g', linestyle = '--')
plt.axvline(x = 1991, color = 'y', linestyle = '--')
```

Actually, this is kinda a follow-up question that I asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74090700/i-want-to-sum-the-gdp-per-capita-for-all-the-countries-in-europe-for-all-the-ye). I appreciate the help.